# Ruby on rails model method is not getting executed in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, methods, model, execute

**posts_controller.rb destroy method**

```
def destroy

    if !request.xhr?
        render_404
        return
    end

    if user_signed_in?

        if Post.exists?(:post_id => params[:id])

                if Post.post_is_mine(params[:id], current_user.id)

                    @return = { :error => false, :response => "Post deleted" }

                else
                    @return = { :error => true, :response => 'You are not allowed to perform this action.' }
                end

            else
                @return = { :error => true, :response => 'This post doesn\'t exist.' }
            end

        else
            @return = { :error => true, :response => 'Please login before you delete a post.' }
        end

    render :json => ActiveSupport::JSON.encode( @return )

end
```

**post.rb**

```
  def self.post_is_mine(post_id, user_id)
    #where(:user_id => user_id, :post_id => bucket_id)
    where("user_id = ? and post_id = ?", user_id, bucket_id)
  end
```

when i check what queries are being run when i destroy a post, i can only see the `.exists?` to run but not the `.post_is_mine` which simply goes through **as it returns TRUE**

i tried several other names as the method since something could cause the problem or even simply trying out the if statement with **.post_is_mine** but still, the query was not run

Could there be a problem on the model as to how i use the where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "where" will return an empty collection, which evaluates as truthy. You would need to add a check to see if there are any records in it to get the right true/false.

```
def self.post_is_mine(post_id, user_id)
  where("user_id = ? and post_id = ?", user_id, bucket_id).any?
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  `#where` returns an ActiveRecord Relation, which is used to generate your query.  The relation will not be evaluated in your code, so the query from `.post_is_mine` will never be executed.  `if Post.postis mine(params[:id], current_user.id)` returns `true` because the Relation object is not `nil`.

What you really want is to use `exists?` in the `post_is_mine` method.

```
def self.post_is_mine(post_id, user_id)
  exists?(:user_id => user_id, :post_id => bucket_id)
end
```

EDIT:

I was curious about the difference between my answer and Pavling's answer.  For anyone else wondering:

`#exists?` executes a SQL statement with `SELECT 1 FROM ...`

`#any?` executes a SQL statement with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...`

In practice there is likely not much difference between the two, but some crude benchmarks indicated that `#any?` is faster (with AR 3.2.6 and Postgresql 9.1 on OSX)

Comment: thanks for the extended information, really helped me understand the difference there